# Show no top panel for Chromium using Gnome 3

Tags: fedora, chromium, gnome3

I am running the new Fedora 19 release, so I am using Gnome 3. I also do use Chromium and I would like to remove the top bar for Chromium as  it only shows the title information of the currently opened tab, which is also shown in the tab itself. It seems superfluous to me.

How can I remove the title bar for chromium?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this was not particularly helpful, but I did manage to find a solution anyways. It does not exactly what I intended, but instead removes the title bar for *all* windows when maximized. Good enough for now.

Basically you have to edit the theme style. If you are using the default Adawaita theme you have to edit the file */usr/share/themes/Adwaita/metacity-1/metacity-theme-3.xml* in the section `frame_geometry name="max"` to the following:

```
<frame_geometry name="max" has_title="false" title_scale="medium" parent="normal" rounded_top_left="false" rounded_top_right="false">
         <distance name="left_width" value="0" />
         <distance name="right_width" value="0" />
         <distance name="left_titlebar_edge" value="0"/>
         <distance name="right_titlebar_edge" value="0"/>
         <distance name="title_vertical_pad" value="0"/>
         <border name="title_border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
         <border name="button_border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
         <distance name="bottom_height" value="0" />
</frame_geometry>
```

More details can be found at http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-remove-maximized-windows.html [Method 2]